# Simulate Photoshop's Multiply in PHP with gd or ImageMagick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd

Having until now only used PHP's gd image library to resize, crop and greyscale images I'm currently struggling to find a way to simulate what happens when, in Photoshop, you place a coloured layer over a greyscale image and select 'multiply' from the layer effects menu. Or, as my old print lecturer would explain it, I need to make a duotone.

For some reason I had thought that all I needed to do was to simply turn the image greyscale and then drop a coloured layer with an transparency value less than 100% over the top. Once I'd done this I wondered why I ever thought I'd get anything other than washed-out.

Having then trawled the gd library documentation, all I could find was the `IMG_EFFECT_OVERLAY` filter to use with `imagelayereffect` but the result of this keeps the white of my greyscale image white rather than making it red.

I haven't used ImageMagick before (but this is one of those rare occasions where I have control over the server so I can install it if I need to) and, having glanced at the documentation in the past, I had presumed that something like Photoshop's `multiply` would be one of its default filters. Alas no.

My tired brain is struggling to understand what Photoshop's `multiply` is actually doing on a pixel by pixel basis so I don't what, if any, series of ImageMagick's (or if possible, gd's) more basic filters I could use to get the result I need.

A deadline looms and Google refuses to return any useful results so any help here would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick *does* have a [multiply operation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=sheg9lu9gfot1i62vb8f4f8qh5#compose). I can't say how close it is to Photoshop's in result and quality (I don't really understand what it does either :), but be sure to try it out.

Comment: I THOUGHT it would have, thank you so so much for the reference. I'll look into this and if it's close then I'll give you the big green tick.

Answer (score 3):

I find this the easiest way to apply Multiply in imagemagick PHP

```
$print = new Imagick("blank.jpg");
$printOverlayTexture = new Imagick("overlay.jpg");
$print->compositeImage($printOverlayTexture, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MULTIPLY, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a collection of handy-dandy ImageMagick scripts. They are not mine, but I frequently find myself referring back to them

[ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/)